# Не работает метод getText() в java (примитивный пример)

Tags: java, gettext

Изучаю События и все такое, есть програмка в которой конпка, и поле текста  в главном классе, при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает событие, обработчик в другом новом классе - открывается окошко с надписью, все норм. Но хотелось чтоб событие читало поле ввода `JTextField Data = new JTextField(20);` и в окошке выводилось введенная надпись. Но выбивает сообщение, будто У обьекта `JTextField Data` нет такого метода как `Data.getText();` Весь код выглядит так:

//........Главный Класс..........

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class Calculator {

    public static void Calc() {     
         JPanel Pn = new JPanel();  
         FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
         Pn.setLayout(fl);

         JLabel info = new JLabel("Counter");   
         JTextField Data = new JTextField("someInitialValue", 20);  
         JButton Plus = new JButton ("Plus");

         CalculatorEngine calcEngine = new CalculatorEngine();
         Plus.addActionListener(calcEngine);
         Data.addActionListener(calcEngine);

         Pn.add(info);  
         Pn.add(Plus);
         Pn.add(Data);

         JFrame visual = new JFrame("Calculator");
         visual.setContentPane(Pn);

         visual.setSize(400,400);
         visual.setVisible(true);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        Calculator.Calc();      
    }
}
```

//........Клас Обработчик..........

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.xml.crypto.Data;

public class CalculatorEngine implements ActionListener {

    String text = Data.getText();// ОШИБКА-Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in other files)

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, text, "Test",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

мне кажется во втором классе вы хотите использовать объект `JTextField Data` из первого класса, чего делать разумеется нельзя, а по факту у вас импортирован класс `javax.xml.crypto.Data`, который не содержит статического метода `getText()`

Полагаю, что лучшим выходом будет передать текст в конструктор `CalculatorEngine`:

```
public class CalculatorEngine implements ActionListener {

    String text;

    public CalculatorEngine(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }     

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, text, "Test",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);        
    }
}
```

И в методе `Calc` замените

```
CalculatorEngine calcEngine = new CalculatorEngine();
```

на

```
CalculatorEngine calcEngine = new CalculatorEngine(Data.getText());
```

Comment: Все норм, Заработало!

Comment: @user198532, рекомендация: старайтесь придерживаться Java Code Conventions при написании кода. Это общепринятые правила написания кода на Java и по этим правилам все переменные следует именовать с маленькой буквы.

Comment: вот ссылка на code conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf